# Google OAuth2 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cors

I have a project on Java(Spring) + JS(React). I did authorization through google oauth2. On localhost my code works perfectly, but when I uploaded my site to the Heroku cloud the following exception appears.

> Access to resource at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id={MyClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20profile&state=cidgievLEUhHBkHigTnGp6IfXkWRiG_eN_OL8EESnMA%3D&redirect_uri=https://my-app.herokuapp.com/oauth2/callback/google' (redirected from 'https://my-app.herokuapp.com/manifest.json') from origin 'https://my-app.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How do i invoke this authorization on JS side >>>

```
      onGoogleSignUpClick = () => {
        window.location.href =
         "https://my-app.herokuapp.com/oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=https://my-app.herokuapp.com/oauth2/redirect";
      };

        <button
           className="google-btn"
           onClick={this.onGoogleSignUpClick}
        >
        </button>
```

My secutiry config class on java side >>>

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                "/",
                "/error",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/**/*.png",
                "/**/*.gif",
                "/**/*.svg",
                "/**/*.jpg",
                "/**/*.html",
                "/**/*.css",
                "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/profile/**","/post/**","/followers/**","/auth/**","/oauth2/**","/ws/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                    .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                    .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                .and()
                    .redirectionEndpoint()
                    .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                .and()
                .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

        http
                .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Also i have WebMvcConfig class >>>

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing authorized domain in OAuth2 client creation. You need to authorize your domain as follows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I set an authorized domain. But it still did not work(